# Cannot find constructor symbol

Tags: java

Here is my code for my Ingredient class:

```
public class Ingredient {

 /* Attribute declarations */
 private String name; //  name
 private int calorieCount; //calorie count

  /* Constructor */
 public Ingredient(String name, int calorieCount) {
  this.name = name;
  this.calorieCount = calorieCount;
 }

 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }

  public int getCalorieCount(){
  return calorieCount;
 }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Ingredient item1 = new Ingredient ("Butter", "100");
    System.out.println(item1);
  }
}
```

When I try and run it, I get a compiler error:

```
1 error found:
File: C:\eclipse\workspace\Assignment NEW1\Ingredient.java  [line: 28]
Error: C:\eclipse\workspace\Assignment NEW1\Ingredient.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Ingredient(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class Ingredient
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A `String` is not an `int`  `"100"` is a String and `100` is an `int`

Comment: @MichelleFrazer.. Welcome to SO. Please mark an answer as accepted. You need to do that whenever you get a helpful answer for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `100` as string in your constructor: -

```
Ingredient item1 = new Ingredient ("Butter", "100");
```

Change it to: -

```
Ingredient item1 = new Ingredient ("Butter", 100);
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I swear everything I learned from my compsci course last year is out the door. If you don't use it, you lose it! Thanks again :)

Comment: @MichelleFrazer.. No problem. Happens sometimes. you're welcome though :)

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to pass second parameter as int. you passed string "100“， however. change it to number 100 instead of "100".

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get compile time error about some symbol is not found, always remember that you have used something in your program which **does not** exist OR it **could not** be found using current class path.